# What Story Maps support replacing the map with a 3D scene?

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d, story-map

I am currently creating story maps to be able to display a 3D scene to users and I am trying to decide which layout works best. Right now I have run into an issue where only certain story maps will allow the main map to be replaced with a URL of a 3D web scene. This is becoming quite difficult to get all of the UI and properties that I want the users to have, while maintaining the 3D component. Is there a list somewhere that can tell me which styles of story maps will support my 3D needs so I can narrow my search down, rather than creating all of these different story maps to find out that it is only supported in 2D format? Right now I know that Journals and Story Map Series are both supported in 3D. Are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now Story Map Journal and Series are the only story map apps that support replacing web page with a web scene. There are plans to improve the experience for adding web scenes into story maps in a future update. Also this FAQ page should help you out with the story maps and the question linked to points out 3D suppport.

http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/faq/#question23

When the 4.0 JS API is out in a final state the 3D experience will become more deeply integrated with the story maps.

Cheers
Russ